# php in HTML file using VS code

Tags: php, html, visual-studio-code

In an HTML file using VS code I'm trying to execute a php statement.
(just the body showing for this example)

```
<body>

 <?php echo "hello world!"; ?>
</body>
```

The leading "<" in the statement is red indicating an error. Is there a VS code extension I need?

I tried installing intellisense extension but without success to fix the "<" red error.

Comment: Did you install PHP Extension Pack?

Comment: Does the file have the PHP extension?  PHP code will normally be ignored by the server  for a .HTM / .HTML file.

Comment: No it is an html file called miniproj.html. I thought the instructor in the class I'm taking put the php statement in an html file. But now I see it's a .php file. I think that is the issue. Thanks. I'm learning - slowly. lol

Comment: I did not install the php extension pack. There are many. Which one do you recommend?

Comment: I see that it is called php extension pack. Adding it now. It can't hurt. But I think the answer to my question was to name the file a .php file and not and .html file. It was confusing because the bulk of the file is html.

Comment: At the status bar you can select which language the file is.